# Is it possible to hide data in a bitmap using LockBits?

Tags: c#, encryption, bitmap, steganography

I'm writing a small steganography application in C# and was able to hide text in images. However the method I used was the `GetPixel/SetPixel` method which was a lot slower for larger images, which I noticed after trying to hide a mp3 file in the image. After some google searches, I found out about `LockBits`. While the speed did improve drastically, I discovered that I was unable to extract the encrypted data (the cipher text) which was hidden in the image.

I'm not sure if the issue is with how I insert the data or when extracting it. When attempting to extract the Base64 cipher text, it would be corrupted (random symbols and characters) and throw an exception about it not being a Base64String. I ended up changing the code by following what was on the documentation for `LockBits`, I'll paste it below.

**Merging the cipher text**

```
public static unsafe void MergeEncryptedData(string data, Bitmap bmp, string output) {
    State s = State.HIDING;

    int height = bmp.Height;
    int width = bmp.Width;

    var bitmapData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
    byte * scan0 = (byte * ) bitmapData.Scan0;

    int bytesPerPixel = 4;
    int dataIndex = 0;
    byte dataValue = 0;
    long colorUnitIndex = 0;
    int zeros = 0;
    byte R, G, B;

    Parallel.For(0, height, (i, loopState) = > {

        byte * currentLine = scan0 + (i * bitmapData.Stride);

        for (int j = 0; j < (bitmapData.Width * bytesPerPixel); j += bytesPerPixel) {
            R = currentLine[i + 2];
            G = currentLine[i + 1];
            B = currentLine[i];

            for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {

                if (colorUnitIndex % 8 == 0) {
                    if (zeros == 8) {
                        if ((colorUnitIndex - 1) % 3 < 2) {
                            currentLine[i + 2] = R;
                            currentLine[i + 1] = G;
                            currentLine[i] = B;
                            //bmp.SetPixel(j, i, Color.FromArgb(R, G, B));
                        }
                        loopState.Stop();
                    }

                    if (dataIndex >= data.Length) {
                        s = State.FILL_WITH_ZEROS;
                    } else {
                        dataValue = (byte) data[dataIndex++];
                    }
                }

                switch (colorUnitIndex % 3) {
                case 0:
                    {
                        if (s == State.HIDING) {
                            B += (byte)(dataValue % 2);
                            dataValue /= 2;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    {
                        if (s == State.HIDING) {
                            G += (byte)(dataValue % 2);
                            dataValue /= 2;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    {
                        if (s == State.HIDING) {
                            R += (byte)(dataValue % 2);
                            dataValue /= 2;
                        }
                        currentLine[i + 2] = R;
                        currentLine[i + 1] = G;
                        currentLine[i] = B;
                        //bmp.SetPixel(j, i, Color.FromArgb(R, G, B));
                    }
                    break;
                }

                colorUnitIndex++;

                if (s == State.FILL_WITH_ZEROS) {
                    zeros++;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    bmp.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
    bmp.Save(output, ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

**Extracting the cipher text**

```
public static unsafe string ExtractData(Bitmap bmp) {
    int height = bmp.Height;
    int width = bmp.Width;

    var bitmapData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
    byte * scan0 = (byte * ) bitmapData.Scan0.ToPointer();

    int bytesPerPixel = 4;
    int colorUnitIndex = 0;
    int charValue = 0;
    string extractedText = String.Empty;

    Parallel.For(0, height, (i, loopState) = > {

        byte * currentLine = scan0 + (i * bitmapData.Stride);

        for (int j = 0; j < (bitmapData.Width * bytesPerPixel); j += bytesPerPixel) {

            for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++) { //this particular loop feels incorrect

                switch (colorUnitIndex % 3) {
                case 0:
                    {
                        charValue = charValue * 2 + currentLine[i] % 2;
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    {
                        charValue = charValue * 2 + currentLine[i + 1] % 2;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    {
                        charValue = charValue * 2 + currentLine[i + 2] % 2;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                colorUnitIndex++;

                if (colorUnitIndex % 8 == 0) {
                    charValue = reverseBits(charValue);

                    if (charValue == 0) {
                        loopState.Stop();
                    }

                    char c = (char) charValue;
                    extractedText += c.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    bmp.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
    return extractedText;
}
```

An example of what the extracted cipher text looks like when the error is thrown:
`I$I$I$I$I$I$I$I$I$I$I$I$I$I䥉II!J$$`.
It should be a Base-64 String

Just for reference, I'm using a LUT PNG image to hide the data, so I'm able see a slight difference in color when compared to the original. So I know the RGB values are indeed being changed.

Comment: Yes you can hide data with out without lockbits.

Comment: To attract an answer, you may need to simplify this down to a [mcve].  Have you tried to determine which of `MergeEncryptedData()` or `ExtractData()` behave differently than the old `GetPixel()` and `SetPixel()` versions?   Asking us to figure out which of the two methods has a bug is a little outside the scope of a stack overflow question.

Comment: First, compare the output of  `MergeEncryptedData()` with the old `SetPixel()` version; if there is a difference then that would indicate a problem with `MergeEncryptedData()`.  Next, try sending valid output from the old `SetPixel()` version to `ExtractData()`.  If there's an error then there's a bug in `ExtractData()`.  Once you figure out where there is a problem you can update your question with more precise information and a sample of the old code that did work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider:

- Stride - image data with may be different of image width. [More info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/image-stride).
- Image number of color/data channels

  - 8 bpp (1 channel)
  - 24 bpp (3 channels RGB)
  - 32 bpp (4 channels ARGB, where A means alpha, transparency)

[image]

You mention RGB PNG but you are using 4 channels in your code (ARGB), double check that.

Here is a sample method that WILL obtain the same data that using the slow Bitmap GetPixel, but really fast. Based on this sample you can fix your code, as:

- How to calculate bits per pixel
- How to use stride properly
- How to read multiple channels

Code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get pixel directly from unmanaged pixel data based on the Scan0 pointer.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bmpData">BitmapData of the Bitmap to get the pixel</param>
/// <param name="p">Pixel position</param>
/// <returns>Pixel value</returns>
public static byte[] GetPixel(BitmapData bmpData, Point p)
{
    if ((p.X > bmpData.Width - 1) || (p.Y > bmpData.Height - 1))
       throw new ArgumentException("GetPixel Point p is outside image bounds!");
    
    int bitsPerPixel = ((int)bmpData.PixelFormat >> 8) & 0xFF;
    int channels = bitsPerPixel / 8;

    byte[] data = new byte[channels];
    int id = p.Y * bmpData.Stride + p.X * channels;
    unsafe
    {
        byte* pData = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i] = pData[id + i];
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```